# прокси на python http.client: проблема с установлением HTTP Connect тунеля: OSError: Tunnel connection failed: 404 Not Found

Tags: python, python-3.x, proxy

Здравствуйте, не могу установить прокси на http.client

```
# coding: utf-8

import http.client

request =  http.client.HTTPConnection('ip-api.com')
request.set_tunnel('77.73.65.173', 3128)
request.request('GET', '/json')
response = request.getresponse()
source = response.read()
request.close()

print(source)
```

> OSError: Tunnel connection failed: 404 Not Found

подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём проблема?

такие же самые прокси использую через urllib.request, там всё работает, а в http.client нет..

Comment: решил проблему таким способом

`import http.client

request =  http.client.HTTPConnection('77.73.65.173', 3128)
request.set_tunnel('ip-api.com')
request.request('GET', '/json')
response = request.getresponse()
source = response.read()
request.close()

print(source)`

Comment: @jfs, добавил решение в тему

Comment: @jfs, Понял. Благодарю)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Решил проблему таким способом:**

```
# coding: utf-8

import http.client

request =  http.client.HTTPConnection('77.73.65.173', 3128) # указываем прокси
request.set_tunnel('ip-api.com') # указываем хост, к которому хотим обратиться
request.request('GET', '/json') # указываем get
response = request.getresponse()
source = response.read()
request.close()

print(source)
```

Comment: словами в вашем ответе стоит упомянуть в чём отличие от кода в вопросе (что в `HTTPConnection` следует прокси указывать (куда вы CONNECT запрос посылаете), а в `set_tunnel()` имя хоста, который вы хотите достичь (куда GET должен попасть). Это легко перепутать, но [в документации есть явный пример](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPConnection.set_tunnel). Спустя какое-то время, вы можете [ответ принять (галочку слева нажать).](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: @jfs, Спасибо больше за разъяснения!)